# Installing 'bcrypt' on sails js difficulty

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js, bcrypt

I tried installing bcrypt on sails js but having the below error

`$ npm install bcrypt
npm ERR! path C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\concat-stream\node_modules\readable-stream
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\concat-stream\node_modules\readable-stream' -> 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\concat-stream\node_modules\.readable-stream.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent`

`npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-18T19_20_51_652Z-debug.log`

I have already installed its dependencies using the below which was successful.

`npm install -g node-gyp
 npm install --g --production windows-build-tools`

Please I need help to rectify the problem

Comment: May be a known issue: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17444

Comment: Thanks. I followed the thread and remove the `package-lock.json` and the `bcrypt` ran successfully.

Comment: If your program is a known-to-work state, I recommend readding a new package-lock.json. It's there to ensure you get a known state of your dependencies.

Comment: Yeah. Sails took note of that. It was added back when I start the server `sails lift`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python2.7
```

or

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

then run

```
npm install bcrypt
```